# asp:Login control requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, authentication

ran into an issue, we are using webforms with a site with this dir structure:

root: /
secure : /securepages/

we only want users who are logged in to access /securepages/.

currently we are using the login control, 3.5, forms auth, all is working ok but know we have thrown assl cert into the mix and the issue is that the login control is requesting WebResource.axd?d=XukT0PE1PS-iOKw3RT8Z6g2&t=633834231612265882 from the non secure url e.g. http://www.example.com/WebResource.axd?d=XukT0PE1PS-iOKw3RT8Z6g2&t=633834231612265882 . This causes the browser to prompt the user to download unsecure content. 
I am using some redirecting in the global.asax to handle redirection to https://xx xxxlogin.aspx if login.aspx it requested from http://.

Comment: have you tried setting require ssl on the forms auth setting in the web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

we are also using a login status control so I am doing more digging.

Answer (score 0):

sorted now with a redirect on the WebResource.axd request...